# Issues with UnityWebRequest.Post not posting data to PHP

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

My project requires contacting a PHP script hosted online. First the project should post a string to the PHP to be processed and returned from the PHP. So in my C#, I call UnityWebRequest.Post followed by UnityWebRequest.Get. Only the Post has issues. The Get request works perfectly as intended (the PHP returns a default set of data if the Post request doesn't do anything).

```
List<IMultipartFormSection> dataForm = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
dataForm.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("difficulty=Easy"));

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(webpage, dataForm);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

This was the latest method I attempted using. Previously I used WWWForms and also tried to Post the string directly into the method. None of these worked. The Get request in Unity works fine, so I figured it might be the PHP that might be the problem.

```
$difficulty = $_POST["difficulty"];
if (!isset($difficulty)) {
    $difficulty = "Hard";
}
```

But I wasn't convinced the PHP was broken since it works perfectly if $difficulty is set using the GET method through the URL (currently the project is using WebClient from System.Net and works perfectly which further convinces me that the PHP isn't the issue). So what's exactly the issue with UnityWebRequest.Post here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a comma not equal operator.

```
dataForm.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("difficulty", "Easy"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work. It does the same thing - the POST request does nothing but the GET request works fine and returns the default data. Also, when logging the response code after the POST, Unity returns 0. I know 200 is success. I assume 0 is a time out. MultipartFormDataSection doesn't have to be used, it was just my last attempt before switching. Any solution works as long as UnityWebRequest is used and the POST works.